# How to iteratively render hierarchical unlimited depth tree structure in react

Tags: reactjs, recursion, tree, iteration, hierarchy

I've created a hierarchical tree structure and want to render it two ways: recursively and iteratively. The structure can have unlimited number of children. I've managed to render that structure recursively, however, I can't seem to solve how can it be done iteratively.

Here is my structure:

```
  const nodes = [
    {
      name: "node 1",
      children: [
        {
          name: "node 1-1",
          children: [
            {
              name: "node 1-1-1",
              children: [
                {
                  name: "node 1-1-1-1",
                  children: [],
                },
                {
                  name: "node 1-1-1-2",
                  children: [],
                },
              ],
            },
            { name: "node 1-1-2", children: [] },
          ],
        },
        {
          name: "node 1-2",
          children: [],
        },
        {
          name: "node 1-3",
          children: [],
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "node 2",
      children: [],
    },
  ];
```

Code I have written for recursive solution:

```
  const getTreeRecursively = (nodes: any) =>
    nodes?.map((node: any) => {
      if (node.children?.length === 0) {
        return (
          <div
            style={{
              textAlign: "left",
              marginLeft: "15px",
            }}
          >
            <div>***{node.name}</div>
          </div>
        );
      }
      return (
        <div
          style={{
            textAlign: "left",
            marginLeft: "15px",
          }}
        >
          <div>***{node.name}</div>
          {getTreeRecursively(node.children)}
        </div>
      );
    });

  return <>{getTreeRecursively(nodes)}</>;
```

Here's how it looks like:

[Example how structure is rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74HqK.png)

Now regarding the iterative solution, I've researched the internet and found a solution with a flattened array. However, this solution does not enable me to render the structure, but just to rearranges the flat array into the same structure that I have for the recursive solution. Was thinking that maybe the flat structure could be somehow rendered in react.

```
  const flat = [
    { id: 1, parentId: 3 },
    { id: 3, parentId: 8 },
    { id: 4, parentId: 6 },
    { id: 6, parentId: 3 },
    { id: 7, parentId: 6 },
    { id: 8, parentId: null },
    { id: 16, parentId: null },
    { id: 10, parentId: 8 },
    { id: 15, parentId: 8 },
    { id: 13, parentId: 14 },
    { id: 14, parentId: 10 },
  ];

  const root = [];

  flat.forEach((node: any) => {
    if (!node.parentId) {
      return root.push(node);
    }

    const parentIndex = flat.findIndex((el: any) => el.id === node.parentId);
    if (!flat[parentIndex].children) {
      return (flat[parentIndex].children = [node]);
    }

    return flat[parentIndex].children.push(node);
  });

  console.log(root);
```

[image of the console logged root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQoAJ.png)

Tried recursive solution and succeeded, however, couldn't manage to render hierarchy tree with unlimited depth iteratively.

Comment: Why is the recursive solution not good enough for you?

Comment: @trincot Just as a proof of concept in my development team that it can be done and recurssion might be memory intensive.

Comment: Are you asking for using the flat structure? On its own, or together with the hierarchical structure? If on its own, where do you get the `name` from. If together, why is the memory for that flat structure not a concern while you worry about the memory used by recursion? (which on an average tree will be less if done well)

Comment: @trincot at first I was trying to render it out with the hierarchical structure that is the first code in my question. However, couldn't find a solution, thus tried to do so with a flat structure and managed to get the same structure as in the first code snippet, but now can't figure out how can it be rendered in react to display it like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/74HqK.png.

Answer (score 0):

The recursive approach is the way to go: on average the stack space used is O(log) (where  is the number of nodes in the tree), and in the worst case it is O().

You could make this iterative by maintaining the path to the current node in an explicit stack variable:

```
const getTreeIteratively = (nodes) => {
  const stack = [[nodes, 0, []]];
  while (stack.length > 0) {
    const [children, i, elements] = stack.at(-1);
    if (i >= children.length) {
      stack.pop();
      if (stack.length == 0) return elements;
      const up = stack.at(-1);
      up[2].push(
        <div
          style={{
            textAlign: "left",
            marginLeft: "15px",
          }}
        >
          <div>***{up[0][up[1]++].name}</div>
          {elements}
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      stack.push([children[i].children ?? [], 0, []]);
    }
  }
}
```